# Why does a Kafka cluster need a Controller when it already uses Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka

A Kafka cluster has a controller node and a Zookeeper cluster, both with their own set of responsibilities. **What is the requirement of the controller when we have zookeeper already ?**
For example : Controller election is performed by zookeeper, a partition leader election is done by controller. *Why doesn't Kafka use Zookeeper also for Partition Leader election when it already has the information of what partitions are on what nodes and which nodes are actually active*.

In short, I am struggling to understand the requirement of controller in spite of the zookeeper being present. It would be really helpful if someone could explain the reason for this design choice and the advantages.

Answer (score 1):

kafka uses zookeeper for a few things:

1. cluster membership - the live brokers of a cluster are those who have ephemeral ZK nodes
2. leader election - election of the kafka broker that acts as a controller
3. state storage - some (mostly the older) state is stored in ZK - the configuration for topics, for example. some state that used to be in ZK has been migrated to special topics (consumer offsets) and some newer functionality was written to store state entirely in kafka (transaction logs, for example).

the general trend is to stop using state in ZK and instead self-host it (although older parts of the code have never been migrated out).

as for why not use ZK for partition leader election - one reason is there is logic involved. when electing a cluster leader broker there's no preference - any broker will do. this fits well with how ZK-based leader-election works (1st memeber to create and own an ephemeral znode wins).

when choosing a partition leader, however, you need a little bit more logic. for example - you'd like to elect the leader with the "highest watermark" (with the most up to date data, remember replication is generally async). there's also logic around unclean leader election. ZK alone cannot do that, hence it is done by the controller.

Answer (score -1):

Zookeeper works as a coordination service and Kafka is using zookeeper for the same purpose.

Zookeeper is must by design for Kafka. Because Zookeeper has the responsibility a kind of managing Kafka cluster. It has list of all Kafka brokers with it and Controller of the cluster is selected by Zookeeper and stored there.

Kafka stores minimum information on Zookeeper.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum

Answer (score -1):

in order to protected zookeeper.  without controller, zookeeper needs to trigger too many listeners (equals to broker count), and most of these listener are useless, it is a potential risk for zookeeper,  through controller only controller interact with zookeeper